# Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':is_lock_screen2' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: flutter, zegocloud

I am using zegocloud service to voice and video call.The app is working file until I configure zegocloud.I have configured the app as suggested bt them.
But it gives error as

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring project ':is_lock_screen2'.
        > Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\is_lock_screen2-2.0.1\android\build.gradle' from cache.
        > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
           > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':is_lock_screen2' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I have looked over the internet but does not find the solution.How to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

android/app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.flutter_firebase"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_firebase"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro/'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
apply plugin:"com.google.gms.google-services"
apply plugin:'com.android.application'
// apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
  implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
  implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.3"))
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
}
```